# Social Login - Icon only or Icon with Text?

Tags: website-design, login

There is a Post [here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/84242/icons-only-vs-list-with-icons) but the answer doesn't fit because everyone knows the Social Login Logos.

OK, so right now I implemented the Social Logins into my Website and I am curious if the User experience is better with

1. Four Buttons with Icon only or
2. Four Buttons with Platform Name and the Logo.

Comment: "everyone knows the Social Login Logos".

UX 101 - **Never assume anything**

Answer (score 1):

The only answer is to do some user testing (great cadidate for A/B testing).

Just having icons can be confusing, people might mistake it as links to the product/company social media pages (commonly found on most website headers/footers).

You don't want users to be guessing, and so 'Login with ...' is certainly more useful and obvious.

But it also depends WHERE you are showing the links (context). For example, it may be easier to understand if the icons are on a login form (or a dedcated login page). Example -

[image]

User testing is a good way to validate your designs and concerns, but sometimes it saves time to go with common/usual design practices and focus your energy on more important UX issues.

Answer (score 0):

As long as they're obviously for use for logging in, then this is almost exclusively an aesthetic decision.

Ultimately it's unlikely that a user that doesn't recognise the logo will attempt to use it to log in, and those that do will know what platform it is.